# Convert debugging symbols to files and line numbers

Tags: debugging, stack-trace, debug-symbols, strace, systemtap

I am using strace and SystemTap to obtain stack traces at system calls. What I get currently shows the function name but not the file name and line number. A trace from strace on `ls` using `-k` option:

```
 > /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so(_IO_file_close+0xb) [0x7890b]
 > /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so(_IO_file_close_it+0x120) [0x79f40]
 > /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so(fclose+0x183) [0x6db93]
 > /code/coreutils/src/ls(close_stream+0x1a) [0x1232a]
 > /code/coreutils/src/ls(close_stdout+0x12) [0x9d52]
 > /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so(__run_exit_handlers+0xe8) [0x39658]
 > /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so(exit+0x15) [0x396a5]
 > /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so(__libc_start_main+0xf7) [0x20587]
 > /code/coreutils/src/ls(_start+0x29) [0x4629]
```

Another one from SystemTap again from `ls` with a slight modification of `strace.stp` in the examples:

```
 0x7f17e06eb607 : munmap+0x7/0x30 [/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so]
 0x7f17e0672882 : _IO_setb+0x62/0x70 [/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so]
 0x7f17e0671030 : _IO_file_close_it@@GLIBC_2.2.5+0xb0/0x180 [/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so]
 0x7f17e0665020 : _IO_fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x180/0x210 [/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so]
 0x4122ba : close_stream+0x1a/0x80 [/usr/bin/ls]
 0x40a8b5 : close_stdout+0x15/0xc0 [/usr/bin/ls]
 0x7f17e0632e69 : __run_exit_handlers+0xd9/0x110 [/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so]
 0x7f17e0632eb5 : exit+0x15/0x20 [/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so]
 0x40449c : main+0x1aec/0x2198 [/usr/bin/ls]
 0x7f17e061bb15 : __libc_start_main+0xf5/0x1c0 [/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so]
 0x404b71 : _start+0x29/0x38 [/usr/bin/ls]
```

How do I convert the hexadecimal numbers to get the file names and line numbers?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two possibilities

1. ... manually filtering data through the `addr2line` program (part of binutils).  This may be possible to automate, but clumsy; something like this, except one may have to split the hex addresses and process them one by one.

> ```
> { system(sprintf("addr2line -e /proc/self/exe %s", ubacktrace())) }
> ```

2. ... through systemtap 2.7's `[u]symfile` and `[u]symline` functions.  These functions work by uploading line-record parts of the debuginfo into the systemtap module, which these functions can use to map to kernel|userspace source file/lines.

> ```
> { hexaddr=tokenize(ubacktrace(), " ")
>   ha=strtol(hexaddr,16)
>   printf("%p %s:%s", ha, usymfile(ha), usymline(ha))
>   while (1) {
>       hexaddr=tokenize("", " ") // continue tokenizing
>       if (hexaddr=="") break
>       ha=strtol(hexaddr,16)
>       printf("%p %s:%s", ha, usymfile(ha), usymline(ha))
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution works fine but is slow. I could not get the second one to work at all. it looks like stap is just not looking at the debug info of the userspace packages

Comment: Yeah, some bug must have popped up recently.  Maybe you're hitting https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20288 also.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and creating the bug report.